# Cypher: How to merge two nodes' keys in a third node

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, nodes

in cypher i want to create a node that has attributes of two existing nodes. I know that to "copy" a node the query is: `MATCH (old:Type) CREATE (new:Type) SET new=old` but this allow me to have the keys from just one node. I need a way to join the keys of two nodes and copy that node

```
match (a:Ubuntu1604), (h:Host) CREATE (b:Ubuntu1604) SET b=a,b=h return b
```

will obviously create b equals to h. I need and "append" function

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself.
Solution is simply

```
match (a:Ubuntu1604), (h:Host) CREATE (b:Ubuntu1604) SET b=a, b+=h return b
```